# Applying video filters on a Flash video on Flash Player

Tags: flash, video, filter

We have an ordinary video player built for Adobe Flash Player that streams a video file and plays it on a browser.
However some of the video files aren't clear enough that we need additional video filters like  *sharpness filter* while the others may require *contrast filter* or *hue and tint filter* due to its color balance.

The question is, is there any feature that are provided by Flash Player's core video component to apply those kind of filters **on the fly** at client-side?

Assumption here is that:

- You **cannot re-encode the video files** that are being streamed to the player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  See [ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html), [ConvolutionFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ConvolutionFilter.html), and Grant Skinner's [ColorMatrix](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html) for easy contrast/hue.

Comment: Thanks. They seem to be exactly what we needed.

Comment: @Hongweng Can you give me more detail or any example link how can i accomplish this goal ? i am very new to flash and i am struggling to accomplish same goal.

Comment: @Sean Fujiwara Hi Sean can you give me an example link how exactly i can apply the filter ? thanks.